# UITableView adjust content inset not unitl 1st scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

while trying to create a tableview with a searchBar I encountered the problem that my tableView automatically adjust the contentInset, but not until the 1st scroll. On another tableView, where is no searchBar the problem does not exists. The setup of the searchController is pretty much ripped out of Apples TableSearchWithUISearchController sample.
So my Codes get called by the TableViewController in viewDidLoad:

```
resultsController = [[ResultConstantTVController alloc] init];
searchController = [[BaseSearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:resultsController];
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
searchController.delegate = self;

self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController;
self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;
[self.searchBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[self.searchBar setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
[self.searchBar setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
self.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
```

I tried already to set the tableViews contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior to automatic manually but it still won't take effect until the 1st scroll.

Before firstScroll
[image: Before first Scroll]

After first scroll
[image: After first scroll]

P.S. I am using the beta Version of Xcode, macOS and iOS.

UPDATE:

I managed to bypass the problem by calling

```
[self.navigationController.view layoutSubviews];
```

in viewDidAppear in the TableViewController.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried already to set the tableViews contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior to automatic

That was right, but not quite enough. Problems of this sort are usually solved by also setting the table view's `alwaysBounceVertical` to YES. You need to do this very early in the life of the view controller.

Comment: I would need to see what "it" is. You may not have done it early enough in the life of the view controller. — But that's not a criticism, and I'm not saying this solution is certain; the problem you're describing is definitely a problem, ever since iOS 11. The workaround I'm suggesting was given to me by an Apple employee.